# Chaining DSL methods in Groovy using "in" and "also" cause NullPointerException

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to get DSL command chains working in Groovy. The chain methods used here are `in` and `also` which gives the `NullPointerException: cannot invoke method`

```
FileStudy filestudy(Closure closure)
{
    FileStudy fileStudy = new FileStudy()
    closure.delegate = fileStudy
    closure()
    return fileStudy
}

class FileStudy
{
    List<String> filename= []
    String processname
    String fieldname
    String line=''
    String startdel
    String enddel
    String delimiter
    def fieldvalues=[]
    String patternstartstring
    String patternendstring
    boolean launchstatus=0
    List<String> matchfieldvalues=[]
    List<String> andmatchfieldvalues=[]
    String andfiltervalues=""

    void file(String... filename)
    {
        this.filename=filename
    }

    void valuebetween(String startdel, String enddel){    
        this.startdel=startdel
        this.enddel=enddel
    }

    void search(String fieldname, String delimiter='=')
    {
        this.fieldname=fieldname
        this.delimiter=delimiter
        ['in': {it(startdel, enddel)}]
    }

    void alsofilter(String...andfiltervalues)
    {
        for (String eachvalue : andfiltervalues){    
            andmatchfieldvalues.add(eachvalue)
        }
    }

    void filterin (String...filtervalues)
    {
        for (String eachvalue : filtervalues){
            matchfieldvalues.add(eachvalue)
        }
        ['also': {alsofilter(it)}]
    }

    def process={
        println it // My process will be here. 
    }


    void launchfileto(String processname){
        for (String eachfile : this.filename){
            new File (eachfile).eachLine {it-> "$processname"(it)}
        }
    }

    def patternflag (String patternstartstring, String patternendstring="")
    {
        this.patternstartstring=patternstartstring
        this.fieldvalues=fieldvalues
        this.patternendstring=patternendstring
        this.processname='process'
        launchstatus=1
    }

    def showall(){
        launchfileto(processname)
    }
}

filestudy {
    file 'data1.txt','data2.txt'
    patternflag ('start here')
    search ('type') in valuebetween ('[',"]")
    filterin ('hello') also ("hey")
    showall() 
}
```

The exception occurs:

```
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method and() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method also() on null object
```

here `in` works well but `also` shows exception. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to chain methods using `in2` (not `in` since this is a keyword in Groovy) and `also` you have to make sure that methods `search` and `filterin` returns not `null`, but e.g. `Map`

```
Map search(String fieldname, String delimiter = '=') {
    this.fieldname = fieldname
    this.delimiter = delimiter
    ['in2': { it(startdel, enddel) }]
}

Map filterin(String... filtervalues) {
    for (String eachvalue : filtervalues) {
        matchfieldvalues.add(eachvalue)
    }
    ['also': { alsofilter(it) }]
}
```

You also have to modify `valuebetween` method, because at this moment it returns `null` and you chain it with `search` using `in2` and `in2` expects that the method you are chaining with returns a Closure with two String parameters. If you keep `valuebetween` like:

```
void valuebetween(String startdel, String enddel) {
    this.startdel = startdel
    this.enddel = enddel
}
```

you will get:

```
Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object
```

You need something like this:

```
def valuebetween(String startdel, String enddel) {
    this.startdel = startdel
    this.enddel = enddel
    return { String s1, String s2 -> /* do something here */}
}
```

- replace `void` with `def`
- return a Closure with two String parameters

#### Full code

```
FileStudy filestudy(Closure closure) {
    FileStudy fileStudy = new FileStudy()
    closure.delegate = fileStudy
    closure()
    return fileStudy
}

class FileStudy {
    List<String> filename = []
    String processname
    String fieldname
    String line = ''
    String startdel
    String enddel
    String delimiter
    def fieldvalues = []
    String patternstartstring
    String patternendstring
    boolean launchstatus = 0
    List<String> matchfieldvalues = []
    List<String> andmatchfieldvalues = []
    String andfiltervalues = ""

    void file(String... filename) {
        this.filename = filename
    }

    def valuebetween(String startdel, String enddel) {
        this.startdel = startdel
        this.enddel = enddel
        return { String s, String s2 -> /* do something here */}
    }

    Map search(String fieldname, String delimiter = '=') {
        this.fieldname = fieldname
        this.delimiter = delimiter
        ['in2': { it(startdel, enddel) }]
    }

    void alsofilter(String... andfiltervalues) {
        for (String eachvalue : andfiltervalues) {
            andmatchfieldvalues.add(eachvalue)
        }
    }

    Map filterin(String... filtervalues) {
        for (String eachvalue : filtervalues) {
            matchfieldvalues.add(eachvalue)
        }
        ['also': { alsofilter(it) }]
    }

    def process = {
        println it // My process will be here.
    }


    void launchfileto(String processname) {
        for (String eachfile : this.filename) {
            new File(eachfile).eachLine { it -> "$processname"(it) }
        }
    }

    def patternflag(String patternstartstring, String patternendstring = "") {
        this.patternstartstring = patternstartstring
        this.fieldvalues = fieldvalues
        this.patternendstring = patternendstring
        this.processname = 'process'
        launchstatus = 1
    }

    def showall() {
        launchfileto(processname)
    }
}

filestudy {
    file 'data1.txt', 'data2.txt'
    patternflag('start here')
    search('type') in2 valuebetween('[', "]")
    filterin('hello') also("hey")
    showall()
}
```

#### Output

It throws `FileNotFoundException` in my case because I don't have `data1.txt` file.

```
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data1.txt (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: data1.txt (No such file or directory)
    at FileStudy.launchfileto(dsl.groovy:60)
    at FileStudy.showall(dsl.groovy:73)
    at avg$_run_closure1.doCall(dsl.groovy:82)
    at avg$_run_closure1.doCall(dsl.groovy)
    at avg.filestudy(dsl.groovy:4)
    at avg$filestudy.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at avg.run(dsl.groovy:77)
```

Comment: Actually this code is for Command chaining. See the line `search ('type') in valuebetween ('[',"]")` here the word `in` is the command chain for both methods `search()` and `valuebetween()`. Likewise i am using `also` but i can't. see the reference [link](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html#_script_base_classes)

Comment: @Bhanuchander_U Got it. I will check this command chain then. Btw, `in` does not work as you expect - `in` is a keyword in Groovy. Change it to e.g. `in2` inside `search` method and in the invocation and you will get NPE in this place as well.

Comment: OMG. i thought it was working. But how to fix this problem..!

Comment: @Bhanuchander_U I've found a solution to fix those exceptions. Answer updated.

Comment: Sorry.Even after modification, again i am getting same error. It can't reach the line `Caught: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method call() on null object` as you mention. Could you please check that you mentioned all the changes you made.

Comment: @Bhanuchander_U Here is an example with all mentioned changes provided - https://gist.github.com/wololock/143282662ddcc2fe32fd2bf7534b9e59 I run it with groovy 2.4.10. Of course it causes `Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: data1.txt (No such file or directory)` due to the fact I don't have data1.txt file. Here is the output I get when I run this script - https://gist.github.com/wololock/4d800a12ef41984dd5006e5f3be2ac2f

Comment: @Bhanuchander_U The exception you get suggests you haven't changed `valuebetween` method in your class. When I revert it to the version you have provided I get the same exception. I posted a full example to the answer as well with the output I get when running a script.

Comment: Thanks a lot. now only i realize where i did mistake. saved my day :)

Comment: @Bhanuchander_U I'm glad I could help you :) Good luck and happy hacking!